# Abrir fichero JSON en Django

Tags: json, django

Estoy intentando trabajar con archivo `json` en mi proyecto `django` y me provoca un error, no encuentra el archivo.

> [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data/arxiu.json'

He hecho el `import json` y mi programa es muy sencillo, ¿alguien puede ayudarme a entender donde estoy fallando?

Código (fichero: views.py)

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import pandas as pd
import json


def coordenadas(request):

    lat = 9.1234567
    lon = 12.1234567

    code = obtener_datos()


    ctx = {'Lat':lat,'Lon':lon, 'code':code}

    return render(request,'map.html', ctx)


def obtener_datos():
    code = 0

    with open('data/arxiu.json') as file:
        file = json.load(file)

    return code
```

Básicamente lo que hago es crear una función que me abra el `arxiu.json` para luego extraer cierta información. Todo iba bien si quito la parte de `with open()...` por lo tanto 100% (además de que la descripción del error es clara) el error es aquí. ¿Podría ser que me falte declarar alguna ruta en `urls.py` u otro lado?

Adjunto una imagen de cómo está ordenado mis documentos del proyecto. Cómo se puede ver la carpeta donde está el fichero está al mismo nivel que `views.py` por lo tanto entiendo que la ruta es `data/arxiu.json`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**EDITO/AÑADO:**
He estado leyendo sobre el tema de `static files`, así que también he probado a meter el fichero dentro de esta carpeta, `static>data>arxiu.json` pero sigue dando el mismo error, no encuentra el archivo.

¡Salud y gracias!

Comment: ¿Desde dónde está llamando a `obtener_datos` o `coordenadas`? En el código que muestras no se ve dónde estás usando esas funciones. Te recomendaría usar la biblioteca `pathlib` u `os.path` para trabajar con rutas.

Comment: `obtener_datos` lo llamo desde `coordenadas` y `coordenadas` es la función que llamo desde el navegador ´http://127.0.0.1:8000/mapa/´ pues en `urls.py` he declarado en `urlpatterns = [path('admin/', admin.site.urls), path('mapa/',coordenadas),]`. No sé si esto responde a tu pregunta, estoy aprendiendo Django ahora mismo y no voy muy sobrado